# http.request with connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js

I run following code which is really simple: I create a server listening 9900. Then I wait 1 second (to ensure the server is ready), and issue 1000 requests to this server. I expect all 1000 requests to be finished correctly. Below is my code:

```
const http = require('http');

// create server
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.end('ok')
}).listen(9900)

// issue 1000 requests after 1 second
setTimeout( async function(){
    for(let i=0;i<1000;i++) { // werid: it works well after changing 1000 to 800
        request();
    }
}, 1000 )

// actually I don't care if the Promise is resolved or rejected,
// so I don't await or chain then.
function request() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const option = {
            protocol: 'http:',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9900,
            path: '/',
            agent: false,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        const req = http.request(option, function(res) {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let body = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log(body)
                resolve(body)
            });
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
            console.log(e.stack)
            process.exit(1)
        });
        req.end();
    })
}
```

But I got `ECONNREFUSED` error, which seems the machine could not establish more socket. The werid thing is if I change the `for loop` to 800, the error won't show. Is there a potential reason or bug? Thanks.

```
problem with request: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9900
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9900
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time I finally get why the err occurs. In my demo test above I use:

```
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++) { // werid: it works well after changing 1000 to 800
    request();
}
```

It issues too many tcp calls beyond the capability server can handle in about 300 ms (I tested on my laptop).

nodejs `net` module adopts a `backlog` parameter in its `server.listen()` method [api](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/net.html#net_server_listen):

> All listen() methods can take a backlog parameter to specify the
>   maximum length of the queue of pending connections. The actual length
>   will be determined by the OS through sysctl settings such as
>   tcp_max_syn_backlog and somaxconn on Linux. The default value of this
>   parameter is 511 (not 512).

According to above explanation from nodejs document, I update Linux `tcp_max_syn_backlog` and `somaxconn` to a larger number via `sysctl`, and also increase `backlog` in nodejs code:

```
var content = 
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 10

{"code":0}`;

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.end(content);
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('err occurs', err);
    throw err;
}).listen(9900, 'localhost', 4000/*backlog*/)
```

Please note I was using `net.createServer` instead of `http.createServer`, in order to reset the `backlog` to be 4000. (I didn't find where to reset the `backlog` in `http` module, which bother me a lot. Can anyone please explain? Thanks)

And now the error didn't show.

Answer (score 1):

I have no context on why you are attempting to perform 1000 requests to a server using the same file; my assumption is you are trying to do some sort of `stress test`. If that is the case, the I'd highly recommend you use the right tool for this purpose, like `Apache Benchmark`. Here is a [quick link](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/apache/stress-testing-with-apache-benchmark) for it.

Comment: My nodejs server sometimes has the functionality to request Tomcat server to get some data. In this case the full picture is: `user browser --->  nodejs --->  tomcat`.  So I want to test the performance of the `nodejs ---> tomcat` process.

Comment: The performance of my nodejs server can be up to 2000 request per second on my laptop. So I make 1000 requests to the fake tomcat server(the nodejs server listening 9900) to see if `http.request` works.

Comment: In that case, you should be making those 1000 requests from node to a real tomcat server. If you really need that amount of requests I would start exploring different solutions to better use your computer/server resources like child processes.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I can test on a real case, but I just wonder why the 800 works while the 1000 doesn't.  Is it because `http.request` run out of the available port or trigger some limitation?